# Apply xslt tokenize function to results of apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a block of XML that is formatted thusly:

```
<line n="2">
      <orig>of right hool herte <ex>&amp;</ex> in our<ex>e</ex><note place="bottom" anchored="true" xml:id="explanatory">Although “r” on the painted panels of the chapel is consistently written with an otiose mark when it concludes a word, the mark here is rendered more heavily and with a dot indicating suspension above the r. This rendering as “our<ex>e</ex>” is a linguistic outlier for the area based on the electronic <emph rend="italic">Linguistic Atlas of Late Medieval English</emph>’s linguistic profiles for “oure,” “our,” and “our<ex>e</ex>.” See eLALME's <ref target="http://archive.ling.ed.ac.uk/ihd/elalme_scripts/mapping/user-defined_maps.html">User Defined Maps</ref> for more information. Unfortunately the current online version (as of 12 July 2014) does not allow direct linking between static dotmaps and linguistic profiles.</note> best entent</orig>
</line>
```

I need to be able to reduce it to just the plaintext: "of right hool herte & in oure best entent," and then tokenize on the space to get a list of either comma or tag-separated values.  I have the bit for the plaintext completed via the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:line" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orig">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note"/>
```

However, I can't get the tokenize function to work with apply-templates.  If I attempt to use value-of instead then the tags underneath the  tag no longer work right.  Is there a way I can run the apply-templates on the xml, then tokenize each element in a single xslt?  Thanks!

Comment: I dont see you calling `tokenize'  anywhere in the code example.

Comment: What is the intended result of this exercise?  -- Note: your first three templates appear to be redundant, as the built-in template rules would do the same.

Comment: I'm not calling tokenize because it does not work at all with apply-templates.  If I call it with value-of, say for example as select="tokenize(.,' ') "then the suppression of note no longer works or it tokenizes items like the e in "oure" that have been wrapped in a tag.

Comment: Also, I know the templates look redundant here, but basically if I don't lay them out like this the larger sheet it's a part of doesn't always display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to be able to reduce it to just the plaintext: "of right hool
>   herte & in oure best entent," and then tokenize on the space to get a
>   list of either comma or tag-separated values.

Not sure what "tag-separated values" means. Given the following **test input**:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <line n="2">
          <orig>of right hool herte <ex>&amp;</ex> in our<ex>e</ex><note place="bottom" anchored="true" xml:id="explanatory">Although “r” on the painted panels of the chapel is consistently written with an otiose mark when it concludes a word, the mark here is rendered more heavily and with a dot indicating suspension above the r. This rendering as “our<ex>e</ex>” is a linguistic outlier for the area based on the electronic <emph rend="italic">Linguistic Atlas of Late Medieval English</emph>’s linguistic profiles for “oure,” “our,” and “our<ex>e</ex>.” See eLALME's <ref target="http://archive.ling.ed.ac.uk/ihd/elalme_scripts/mapping/user-defined_maps.html">User Defined Maps</ref> for more information. Unfortunately the current online version (as of 12 July 2014) does not allow direct linking between static dotmaps and linguistic profiles.</note> best entent</orig>
    </line>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="line"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:variable name="line-text">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@n"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(normalize-space($line-text), ' ')" separator=", "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <line n="2">of, right, hool, herte, &amp;, in, oure, best, entent</line>
</root>
```

Comment: Just curious as why you answered the question when the OP didn't even show an attempt to? Again, curious.

Comment: @PhilVallone First and foremost, because it was interesting. And once I had the solution, I had nowhere to put it but here. And the OP *did* make an attempt of sorts. When someone is stuck without knowing what direction to turn to, I don't see what point is there in asking them to make an effort for the sake of an effort.  And finally: I am not the OP's mother, and I am not here to check their homework or their fingernails (I could write a *lot* more about this, if you wanted...).

Comment: fair enough!  No need to write more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `tokenize()` to get this output:

```
  of right hool herte & in oure best entent
```

The identity transform along with a template to squelch `note` will do it for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="note"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want it to be comma-separated, you can capture the above text output in a variable, and then apply `tokenize` as you mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="result">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="note"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(tokenize(normalize-space($result), ' '), ',')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT, given your input XML, will yield the following text:

```
of,right,hool,herte,&,in,oure,best,entent
```